# how to find out if PHP and sendmail are working together?

Tags: php, email, command-line, terminal, sendmail

When I use the terminal to send an e-mail things work correctly. I use the following command:

```
echo "Subject: test" | /usr/lib/sendmail -v you@domain.com
```

But when I try this in PHP:

PHP DOCUMENTATION:

```
<?php bool mail ( string $to , string $subject , string $message [, string $additional_headers [, string $additional_parameters ]] ) ?>
```

MY IMPLEMENTATION:

```
<?php mail("you@domain.com", "my topic", "my message contents", "From: me@domain.com"); ?>
```

, then it is not working. Why is that? I guess it has to do with PHPs php.ini file?

All I configured:

- open php.ini:

  `nano /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
- uncomment sendmail_path and write:

  `sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail`
- uncomment sendmail_from and write:

  `sendmail_from = me@domain.com`
- restart apache:

  `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

What can be the case? To make this extra clear: I want PHP to be able to e-mail!

**EDIT:**

- The PHP mail() function returns a FALSE.
- for php.ini: changing `/usr/sbin/sendmail` into `/usr/lib/sendmail` (or the other way around) does not seem to make any difference
- for terminal command: changing `/usr/sbin/sendmail` into `/usr/lib/sendmail` (or the other way around) does not seem to make any difference either
- I sent messages to both my own domain and to gmail, both without messages in the spam folder.

The logfiles of Sendmail:

```
root@machine:/var/log# cat mail.warn

root@machine:/var/log# cat mail.err

root@machine:/var/log# cat mail.log
Mar 20 10:17:09 machine sendmail[12249]: p2K9H2R9012249: from=root, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=1, relay=root@localhost
Mar 20 10:17:20 machine sendmail[12253]: p2K9HImw012253: from=root, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=0, relay=root@localhost
Mar 20 10:17:25 machine sendmail[12255]: p2K9HOAC012255: from=root, size=0, class=0, nrcpts=1, relay=root@localhost
Mar 20 10:20:00 machine sendmail[12277]: p2K9K09k012277: from=root, size=14, class=0, nrcpts=3, msgid=<201103200920.p2K9K09k012277@machine.domain.com>, relay=root@localhost
Mar 20 10:20:00 machine sm-mta[12279]: p2K9K0Ge012279: <-r@machine.domain.com>... User unknown
Mar 20 10:20:00 machine sendmail[12277]: p2K9K09k012277: to=-r, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=90014, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Mar 20 10:20:00 machine sm-mta[12279]: p2K9K0Ge012279: from=<root@machine.domain.com>, size=290, class=0, nrcpts=2, msgid=<201103200920.p2K9K09k012277@machine.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar 20 10:20:00 machine sm-mta[12279]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 20 10:20:02 machine sm-mta[12279]: p2K9K0Ge012279: to=<you@domain.com>, ctladdr=<root@machine.domain.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:02, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=60290, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.77.27], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1300612802 w59si3196382eeh.92)
Mar 20 10:20:02 machine sm-mta[12279]: STARTTLS=client, relay=aspmx.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 20 10:20:04 machine sm-mta[12279]: p2K9K0Ge012279: to=<you2@domain.com>, ctladdr=<root@machine.domain.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:04, xdelay=00:00:02, mailer=esmtp, pri=60290, relay=aspmx.l.google.com. [74.125.79.27], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1300612804 p50si3196335eei.44)
Mar 20 10:20:04 machine sendmail[12277]: p2K9K09k012277: to=you2@domain.com,you@domain.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:04, xdelay=00:00:04, mailer=relay, pri=90014, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (p2K9K0Ge012279 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 20 10:20:04 machine sendmail[12277]: p2K9K09k012277: p2K9K09l012277: DSN: User unknown
Mar 20 10:20:04 machine sm-mta[12279]: p2K9K0Gg012279: from=<>, size=1921, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201103200920.p2K9K09l012277@machine.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar 20 10:20:05 machine sm-mta[12279]: p2K9K0Gg012279: to=<root@machine.domain.com>, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=local, pri=31921, dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent
Mar 20 10:20:05 machine sendmail[12277]: p2K9K09l012277: to=root, delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=31038, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (p2K9K0Gg012279 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 20 10:25:11 machine sendmail[12321]: p2K9PBC3012321: from=root, size=14, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201103200925.p2K9PBC3012321@machine.domain.com>, relay=root@localhost
Mar 20 10:25:11 machine sm-mta[12323]: p2K9PBLe012323: from=<root@machine.domain.com>, size=318, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201103200925.p2K9PBC3012321@machine.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar 20 10:25:11 machine sm-mta[12323]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 20 10:25:12 machine sm-mta[12323]: p2K9PBLe012323: to=<you@domain.com>, ctladdr=<root@machine.domain.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=30318, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.77.27], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1300613112 u12si3204796eeh.99)
Mar 20 10:25:12 machine sendmail[12321]: p2K9PBC3012321: to=you@domain.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30014, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (p2K9PBLe012323 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 20 11:00:17 machine sendmail[12567]: p2KA0HX9012567: from=root, size=20, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201103201000.p2KA0HX9012567@machine.domain.com>, relay=root@localhost
Mar 20 11:00:17 machine sm-mta[12568]: p2KA0HNn012568: from=<root@machine.domain.com>, size=324, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201103201000.p2KA0HX9012567@machine.domain.com>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA-v4, relay=localhost [127.0.0.1]
Mar 20 11:00:17 machine sm-mta[12568]: STARTTLS=client, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com., version=TLSv1/SSLv3, verify=FAIL, cipher=RC4-SHA, bits=128/128
Mar 20 11:00:18 machine sm-mta[12568]: p2KA0HNn012568: to=<you@domain.com>, ctladdr=<root@machine.domain.com> (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=esmtp, pri=30324, relay=gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com. [74.125.77.27], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (OK 1300615218 w59si3268114eeh.65)
Mar 20 11:00:18 machine sendmail[12567]: p2KA0HX9012567: to=you@domain.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=30020, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (p2KA0HNn012568 Message accepted for delivery)
Mar 20 11:16:23 machine sendmail[12675]: p2KAGNg8012675: from=www-data, size=188, class=0, nrcpts=0, msgid=<201103201016.p2KAGNg8012675@machine.domain.com>, relay=www-data@localhost
root@machine:/var/log#
```

**EDIT2:**

I have found the solution!

It was the config in php.ini, as I expected.

In php.ini:

`sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail **-t -i**`

Now, lets also try to understand why, cause I found the -t at [this site](http://askville.amazon.com/setup-php-mail-Linux-server/AnswerViewer.do?requestId=11987907) and then i found the -i in the php.ini file itself. What does -t and -i mean??

`-t` 
   Extract  recipients from message headers. These are added to any recipients specified  on  the  command line. With  Postfix  versions  prior  to 2.1, this option     requires that no recipient addresses are  specified on the command line.

`-i`
   When reading a message from standard  input,  don't treat  a line with only a . character as the end of input.

[source](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html)

Hope I could help those of you that ran in to similar problems.

Comment: "it's not working" is not good information. what error messages do you get? what do you have in your logs?

Comment: Your terminal example uses `/usr/lib/sendmail` but you configured `/usr/sbin/sendmail` in the php.ini

Comment: First sanity check: Have you checked the spam folder? Secondly, does the method return `TRUE` or `FALSE`? `TRUE` means `mail` was at least able to *attempt* to send the e-mail.

Comment: i know you wanna set it up yourself but email can be a tricky one sometimes so i use the codeigniter email class as it sorts out the hassle of checking protocol/bit length /word wrap/ validation ect http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/email.html

Comment: I think you should try your question on one of the SO sister sites like serverfault.com, superuser.com or askubuntu.com - the users there are probably more familiar with troubleshooting these types of issues - SO is more aimed towards programming

Comment: try viewing `/var/log/messages` for the sendmail errors

Comment: Please post your answer as answer (not as part of the question) and then select it as your answer. That does work and will help others. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> What can be the case? To make this extra clear: I want PHP to be able to e-mail!

The case or better the because in your case is, that the `mail()` function and sendmail are two different pair of shoes. They are not related to each other per-se.

So only because you can send emails using the sendmail program this does not mean that the PHP `mail()` function will send emails as well.

What you are facing is a configuration problem of your PHP installation. PHP is pretty good to sending emails by default but PHP is not able to know all setups so in case `mail()` fails you need to check whether or not you've properly configured PHP to send emails.

A good start to learn more what to configure, get tons of notes and notices as well as related information is the PHP manual: [`mail()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php).

A first sanity check - as others have already commented - is to check the return value of the `mail()` function. If it's false, then PHP knows that sending mail has failed.

If it's true and you still don't get the email (out), then some other component is not helpful in transporting the email further on. You need to check the whole chain of the transport and - just to make it bold - you can have multiple errors in your overall configuration that is preventing you sending emails via PHP even in case you are able to send some from the shell.

If this is too complicated for you I suggest you get in contact with a system administrator that can help you in solving your problem.

By the way, you can write your own wrapper and send emails with a shell command: [`shell_exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php), take care.

Comment: system administrator that can help you in solving your problem. that a be a first ;p

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking the mail log file. It's location depends on your system but it can be found in `/var/log/mail.log` on a standard Ubuntu installation. You should try running your PHP code then checking if anything is logged.

Comment: Thanks Ewan Heming, I just added my logfile

Comment: Does the log file tell you anything?

Comment: Did you try re-running the PHP script to see if a new line as added to it?

Comment: Since I removed all mail log files, they are not created anymore.. So I haven't test it yet. But after all, it works now!