# Failed sending mail EC2-PHP with SendMail

Tags: php, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I configured my amazon EC2 instance to send mails with sendmail with the following url:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/sendmail.html
after finished i added the php.ini the following line:

> sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i

I already looked into other solutions, but they didn't help.
[how to find out if PHP and sendmail are working together?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5367779/how-to-find-out-if-php-and-sendmail-are-working-together)

when i try to send email from console it reach the destination.

> sudo /usr/sbin/sendmail -f x@y.com x@gmail.com

but when i tried to run it from code it doesn't work

```
<?php
    $to = "X@y.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from ="w@z.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    $result = mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    if ($result)
    {
        echo "mail sent";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

The result is always true, there is nothing on the logs.
Can someone help, what am i doing wrong here??

Comment: Are you trying to send a message to `gmail.com.com` ?

Comment: sorry i edited the question, the source doesn't include .com.com

Comment: Is result returning true or false? Do you see anything related to the message in /var/log/maillog? Need to narrow down if the issue is with sending, or delivery. Mails sent directly from EC2 often get filtered by the recipient due to amazon IPs being in spamhaus lists.

Comment: The result is always true, there is nothing on the logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting result "true" always then your emails might be blocked by Spamhaus. So the best way is to send email from an ec2 instances is to set relay email to different mail server. You can send 200 emails per day for free using sendgrid. Otherwise you can send email using smtp authentication. [Here is an example using gmail smtp server.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-gmail-smtp-server-from-php-page)

Comment: thanks it might not solved my problem but i used sendgrid and it's working with web API now